# ¿ Pasar el número de posición de un elemento HTML al que hago click a una función?

Tags: javascript, html5

Necesito pasar un valor a una función que es ejecutada mediante un evento. Este valor será el numero de iteración que tenga en un bucle.
O lo que es lo mismo, quiero pasar un numero a una función que identifica al elemento HTML que he pulsado.

Pongo el código:

```
pasos = this.miElemento.getElementsByTagName('li');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < pasos.length; i++) { 
  pasos[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => { miFuncion(i); }); 
}
```

Si pulso el elemento con tag 'li' me llamara a la función `miFuncion` pero el valor de i que recibiré será igual a `pasos.length` y no el valor del numero i que tenga según voy asignando el evento al elemento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones, quizás la más sencilla sería usar `let` en lugar de `var` para definir la variable que se usa para iterar en el bucle.

Al usar `var` estás definiendo la variable `i` como global (o limitada a la función) y su valor al terminar el bucle será el mismo no importa en que `li` pulses. En cambio, `let` tiene ámbito de bloque, es decir, su ámbito es el bloque en el que se define por lo que su valor va a quedarse "congelado" en el que tenía en esa iteración del bucle, en lugar del valor que tenga al final bucle.

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando (nota como la definición de `i` se mueve directamente dentro del bucle y no fuera):

```js
pasos = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (let i = 0; i < pasos.length; i++) {
  pasos[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(i);
  });
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Uno</li>
  <li>Dos</li>
  <li>Tres</li>
</ul>
```

Otras opciones podrían ser: añadir un data-atributo con el orden dentro del bucle, o comparar los elementos del la lista con el pulsado para compararlo. Pero lo propuesto arriba va a ser más limpio y sencillo.

Comment: Probé con 'let' y funciona perfecto. Gracias !